# Product of a vector, a matrix and a vector

Tags: matrices

Given are two n-dimensional column vectors a and c, and an nxn-matrix B.

Transpose is indicated by ', for example a' is the transpose of a, c' is the transpose of c, and B' is the transpose of B.

The matrix elements are written as bij, with i the row index, j the column index (column vector elements are indexed with i only, elements of a row vector are indexed with j)

I want to show that a'Bc = (a'Bc)'= c'B’a.

One tedious way of doing this would be to first noting that a'i = aj for all i=j and writing a'B as follows:

a'B=a1*b11+a2*b21+…+an*bn1; a1*b12+a2*b22+…+an*bn2; … ; a1*b1n+…+an*bnn;

and then multiplying this row vector (a'B) with c to get the following sum ("result 1"):

**result1:**

a'Bc= (a1*b11+a2*b21+…an*bn1)c1 + (a1*b12+a2*b22+…+an*bn2)c2 + …  + (a1*b1n+…+an*bnn)cn

To compare this with c'B’a write B’a as follows:

B’a =

b’11*a1+b’12*a2+…+b’1n*an;

b’21*a1+b’22*a2+…+b’2n*an;

….

b’n1*a1+b’n2*a2+…+b’nn*a;

and multiply c' with this column vector (noting that c'i = cj for all i=j), to get the following sum:

c1(b’11*a1+b’12*a2+…+b’1n*an) + c2(b’21*a1+b’22*a2+…+b’2n*an) + … + cn(b’n1*a1+…+b’nn*an)

noting that b’ij = bji for all i,j and slightly rearranging gives “result 2”:

**result 2:**

c'B'a = (a1*b11+ a2*b21+…+an*bn1)c1 + (a1*b12+a2*b22 +…+ an*bn2)c2 + … + (a1*b1n +…+ an*bnn)cn

which is equal to "result 1" given above for a'Bc, i.e.:

**(a'Bc)' = c'B'a = a'Bc**

An alternative way would be to note that a'Bc is a scalar and the transpose of a scalar is the scalar itself, i.e.

a'Bc = k

k = k'

hence:

a'Bc = (a'Bc)' = c'B'a

is this a valid proof?  I.e. can one say in general that the transpose of whatever product results in a scalar, is equal to that product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $a^TBc$ is a scalar (let's call it $k$), so its transpose is $(a^TBc)^T=k^T=k$ as you can easily guess.

Then, you should remember then when you transpose a product between two matrices (in general, but vectors can be seen as 1-column or 1-row matrices) $XY$ you take the transpose of each factor, and swap their multiplication order, so $(XY)^T=Y^TX^T$.
In your equation, take $X=a^T$ and $Y=Bc$, so you have your solution.

Comment: Thank you Davide!  your answer repeats the second proof given in my question - I take that as a confirmation and accept your answer.  I'm only an occasional user of matrix algebra, and hence feel a bit insecure with that stuff, and was just looking for confirmation that as a'Bc = k, then because of k=k' we have also a'Bc = c'B'a.  Would you mind confirming this explicitly, briefly?  Sorry if it seems redundant to you, I just want to make sure, given that I'm really not that confident in this subject.

Comment: I've also edited the question, and replaced S with k, to avoid the impression that S, which was meant to be a scalar, might be a matrix, given that it's a capital letter.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that. However, this is certainly the easiest method since you don't have to bother with those calculations with the coefficients.

Comment: Well, yes it is correct. Anyway, capital letters are just a notation I use, nothing special or conventional in that.

Comment: many thanks!  that helps.